# Incentre and excentre of a triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Prove that the triangle formed by the points of contact of the sides of a given triangle with the excircles corresponding to these sides is equivalent to the triangle formed by the points of contact of the sides of the triangle with the inscribed circle

Comment: what does equivalent mean?

Comment: I think that it means the triangles are congurent

Comment: You don't even know what it means? At least in this problem, the two triangles are not congruent, they have the same area.

Comment: I know and that's what I am telling you

Comment: Moreover I saw this problem in the book and couldn't get it spending hours on it and thus asked you all

Comment: At least you should have sketch the picture to check if the triangles are congruent or not, no?

Comment: I have a property related to it . Orthocentre of excentral triangle is incentre of smaller triangle referred to as pedal triangle . It is useful to solve many problems.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hint: To show the two triangles are equivalent (or having the same area), note that $$area(\triangle AEF)=\frac12(p-a)^2\sin A =\frac 12(p-a)^2\frac{a}{2R} = \frac{(p-a)^2(p-b+p-c)}{4R}$$
where $a,b,c$ are the sides of $\triangle ABC$ and $p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$.

Similarly for the triangles $\triangle AE'E',\dots$

Comment: How will this be helpful ?